# Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на js. хотелось бы понять правильно ли написан кусок кода

Tags: javascript, слайдер

пытаюсь сделать слайдер без прибегания к глобальным переменным, в которых хранится фиксированная длина картинки. Логика такая: получить все картинки из html, после получить ширину каждой и добавить в список. при нажатии на кнопку хранимый индекс картинки увеличивается на единицу, а left увеличивается на цифру из массива по этому индексу.
вот участок кода, который вызывает сомнение:

```
function setImgWidth {
    //получаем все картинки в нужном блоке 
    return function getImgWidth() {
        var img = document.querySelectorAll ( ".slide" );
        return img;
    }
    //добавляем в массив ширину картинок
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {          
            var width = img[i].clientWidth;
            list.push(width);
        }
        return list;
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, что до `var list = [];` дело не дойдет.

Comment: Подтверждаю @Igor, функция просто ретернется на `getImgWidth` и усё...

Comment: Ну и скобочки поставьте после `setImgWidth`.

Comment: я неправильно  получил имеющиеся изображения?

Comment: окей, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так, может чем-нибудь поможет мой вариант.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function setImgWidth() {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
      list = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      list.push(img[i].clientWidth);
    }
    return list;
  }

  var checkList = setImgWidth();

  for (var i = 0; i < checkList.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkList[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="slide">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400" alt="" class="slide">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500" alt="" class="slide">
```

*P.S. пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/vbYwxm?editors=1011)*

Comment: спасибо. честно говоря, вообще не понимаю зачем я запихнул получение картинки в отдельную функцию

Comment: @АндрейШевелёв, ошибки случаются, ничего страшного, желаю успехов!